# Text input focus isn't working as expected on Cordova Android app (but fine on cordova serve in the browser)

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, mobile-application

I have a Cordova app that behaves differently when using the Cordova serve option -
I have a text input field for users to enter a link, if the user hasn't added the http:// or https:// part of the URL this gets automatically prepended to the the start of the string once the string length is greater than 8 characters.

When using cordova serve android to run this app directly in the browser the functionality works as intended, so for instance if I type in the following it changes automatically to include 'http://'

```
www.nba.
```

// string now changes to the following automatically and moves the cursor to the end to allow the user to complete

```
http://www.nba.
```

When I run cordova run android and run this same functionality on the mobile app directly the same code does something very different.

e.g so if i type in the following

```
www.nba.
```

// the string is changed to include the http however the cursor now moves between the 1st and 2nd w (in the www)

e.g it looks like the following:

```
http://w|ww.nba.           // the cursor has moved between the first and second w
```

I have tried this using multiple keyboards including the stock rom keyboard and the same thing happens every time??

The code itself is fairly simple

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^(http|https)://");
 if (pattern.test($scope.post.link) === false) {
     $scope.post.link = 'http://' + $scope.post.link;
}
```

Can anyone suggest why this would happen on the cordova build on the phone but not the actual cordova serve?

Answer (score 0):

i know dont have much sense, but try scaping the forward slashes `new RegExp("^(http|https):\/\/");`